# Reduce time while displaying large geom and merging it using st_union

Tags: postgis

I have multipolygon geom data which is very large in size and also takes a lot of time to display the data on the map and sometimes even in tables in pgAdmin.

The approach I have been trying is `st_dump()` to break down the geometry and get it displayed faster. What can be the best way to minimize loading time without much affect on the data?

Secondly, I am trying to `st_union()` the same category geom data from above into a different table or materialized view. But the data that is supposed to be categorized is very large in number, and also, it takes a plenty of time (around 2-3 hrs).

I tried using `st_simplifypreservetopology()`, but I am afraid that it might affect the total area result of the geom. Is there any better way to optimize code or reduce time without affecting the results?

And also use of `st_quantize()` doesn't seem to help reduce the size and make it run faster.

Comment: I am not sure you can keep your complex multi-polygons, reduce size on disk and improve rendering speed all at once. You may have to give up on one of the objectives (size on disk looks like a good candidate...). Then you can have a look at st_segmentize and/or st_simplify (and it is OK to have several versions of the geometry for different purpose (display, analysis etc))

Comment: Too broad to answer without actual context. *Querying/manipulating* TOASTed geometries adds significant overhead, so dumping into single parts is generally a good idea - even more so for index efficiency. *Loading* data is generally dependent on the total volume to be transferred - since PostgreSQL doesn't stream data from within statements, there is not much to be done if *all data* is what you want to retrieve. Quantizing TOASTed geometries should reduce *on-disk space*, but not memory space footprint when decompressed.